# How to get content of the home page in Shopify Storefront API?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-storefront-api

I am using the menu query to get the main-menu with Shopify GraphQL API.

It returns me menu items and all of that looks good.

```
{
"data": {
    "menu": {
        "id": "gid://shopify/Menu/888734372",
        "title": "Main menu",
        "itemsCount": 4,
        "items": [
            {
                "id": "gid://shopify/MenuItem/62623462",
                "title": "Home",
                "type": "FRONTPAGE",
                "url": "https:/test.myshopify.com/",
                "resourceId": null
            },
            {
                "id": "gid://shopify/MenuItem/251532",
                "title": "Electronics",
                "type": "COLLECTION",
                "url": "https://test.myshopify.com/collections/catalog",
                "resourceId": "gid://shopify/Collection/26262"
            },
            {
                "id": "gid://shopify/MenuItem/888888",
                "title": "Clothing & Accessories",
                "type": "CATALOG",
                "url": "https://test.myshopify.com/collections/all",
                "resourceId": null
            }, 
            {
                "id": "gid://shopify/MenuItem/111111",
                "title": "About",
                "type": "PAGE",
                "url": "https:/test.myshopify.com/pages/about",
                "resourceId": "gid://shopify/Page/111111"
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

It contains a menu item of type FRONTPAGE which is the client's Home page.

How I can make a query to get the response of the content for that FRONTPAGE/Home page?

When I open the front page of the store, I can see there are a few items like this:

- Slideshow
- Trending Products list
- On Sale list
- Men Fashion list

Answer (score 1):

When you want a specific page and the data associated with it, you can use the Page endpoint of the Admin API. As in: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2024-01/resources/page

That will give you at least the basics. Probably not the lists though as that stuff is going to be buried in other template aspects.

Comment: Thanks David. I have tried using page query from the Storefront API, but it does not return anything useful, mostly likely because it is buried behind the template. Would it be the same result to try with the Admin API?

Comment: You cannot mix and match API calls. Storefront is for storefront things. ADMIN API is the backend of a store. So if you expect data to play with in terms of a store, you need to be aware of that difference. Apples are not Oranges!

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. My question was related to the thing that I have tried page query in the Strofront API and it does not return anything useful. I was asking if it would be same if I implement Admin REST API just to make this work.

Comment: Take the few minutes to make a call then to get the Page resource, and inspect the results to see if there is anything of value in there. Nothing beats spending a few minutes doing the work to validate doing the real work!